# F# intellisense in a custom editor

Tags: ide, f#, intellisense

is there a way to migrate F# intellisense into my own editor without having to rewrite its parser and, worst of all, its type inference mechanisms?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[F# intellisense tool](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d371abd932f#samples/compiler/fsintellisense/Program.fs) is available as an independent package including its parser and type inference mechanisms.

I believe it isn't difficult to use the tool in your own editor (see the introduction [here](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=fsharp%20intellisense%20tool)).

Answer (score 2):

See the MonoDevelop F# add-on (I believe written by Tomas Petricek).